# perl hash syntax error on command line

Tags: perl, hash

When I tried hash in command line as in the below example, I am getting syntax error. I tried using fat comma as well but still the same result. Can someone help me?

```
perl -e "%hash_ex=(as,wdesadc,afcsdc,esvdfvzdfvfv,1,sd,34,34);print $hash_ex{'1'};"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "};"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

perl -e "%hash_ex=('a' => 1 , 'b' => 2);print $hash_ex {a};"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "};"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Try using single quote to wrap your Perl command. With you or quote your system will try to interpolate the variables before passing to Perl. Using single quotes will prevent this and the entire command will be passed to perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using double quotes to pass your command to Perl. This will mean that the shell will first interpolate any variables in your string before it then passes the command to Perl. you can see this if you just run echo on the string with double quotes then single quotes. The output from echo will show what the shell is then passing to Perl

When the shell processes the text in the double quotes it interpolates the $hash_ex. Since this is not set in the shell this gets interpolated as nothing which means your print statement instead of being

```
print $hash_ex{a}
```

becomes

```
print {a}
```

So you need to wrap all your perl in singleqotes so that the shell does not interpolate any vars and passes the full string to perl as literal string.

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that your Shell also substitutes variables beginning with `$`:

```
# (on zsh and bash)
echo "%hash_ex=(as,wdesadc,afcsdc,esvdfvzdfvfv,1,sd,34,34);print $hash_ex{'1'};" 
%hash_ex=(as,wdesadc,afcsdc,esvdfvzdfvfv,1,sd,34,34);print {'1'};
```

Because of this, you'll better use single qotes for your `-E` argument:

```
perl -e'%hash_ex=(as,wdesadc,afcsdc,esvdfvzdfvfv,1,sd,34,34);print $hash_ex{1};'
sd
```

if you really need single quotes (in this case you don't), you can use the `q` operator:

```
perl -E'say q~some non-interpolating string\t\n$_~'
some non-interpolating string\t\n$_
```

Or you can try to avoid the interpolating of your shell:

```
perl -e "%hash_ex=(as,wdesadc,afcsdc,esvdfvzdfvfv,1,sd,34,34);print \$hash_ex{'1'};"
```